# R: How to Plot two columns comparative histogram in single plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts, plotly

R: How to Plot two columns comparative histogram in single plot?

```
due_vs_prom <- factor( c(unique(inv$Due_Bin)),levels = c("early","<=5","<=30","<=10","<=50",">50"))
due_counts <- inv %>% group_by(Due_Bin) %>% summarize(count = n())
prom_counts <- inv %>% group_by(Prom_Bin) %>% summarize(count = n())

due_vs_prom <- data.frame(due_vs_prom , due_counts , prom_counts )

plot_due_vs_prom <- plot_ly(due_vs_prom, y = ~due_counts , x = ~ (prom_counts), type = 'bar', name = 'Due_Bin') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~due_counts, name = 'Late Bin') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
```

DataSet like:

```
Promise_Bin             Due_Bin

early                   early             
early                   >50
early                   >50
>50                     >50
>50                     >50
<=50                    <=50
early                   early
early                   early
<=5                     <50
<=5                     <=5
<=30                    <=30
early                   early
<=30                    >50
<=30                    <=30                    
<=10                    <=10
```

Expected plot:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what's wrong with the current code, what does it generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe into a longer format (here using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package), group by the "Bin" and different "categories" to count for each of them and finally plot it using `geom_col`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(var,val) %>% count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = n, fill = var))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
structure(list(Promise_Bin = c("early", "early", "early", ">50", 
">50", "<=50", "early", "early", "<=5", "<=5", "<=30", "early", 
"<=30", "<=30", "<=10"), Due_Bin = c("early", ">50", ">50", ">50", 
">50", "<=50", "early", "early", "<50", "<=5", "<=30", "early", 
">50", "<=30", "<=10")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can also do `count(var, val) %>%` instead of `group_by(var, val) %>% count() %>%`

Comment: Yes, you're right that works too ;). I did not about this way of using `count`. Thanks ;). For now, I found more explicit to `group_by` first and then `count` but I guess it is just my use.